# the argument type 'string ' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'pattern'

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I have a problem that the argument type string can't be assigned to the parameter type pattern in this code I added the null check ! but the error didn't disappear what shall I do? in this problem i coufused the error in this line
caculStr = caculStr.replaceFirst(inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr)?.group(0), 'caculStrTemp$i');

```
  Future<dynamic> handleCalcuStr(String caculStr) async {
var temp = new Map();
if (matrixs.containsKey(caculStr)) {
  return matrixs[caculStr];
}
if (dbs.containsKey(caculStr)) {
  return dbs[caculStr];
}
if (num.tryParse(caculStr) != null) {
  return num.tryParse(caculStr);
}
if (ufTemp.containsKey(caculStr)) {
  return ufTemp[caculStr];
}
caculStr = formatCmdStr(caculStr);
if (caculStr.contains('(')) {
  var caculStrs = [];
  int index = -1;
  List<String> stack = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < caculStr.length; i++) {
    if (caculStr[i] == '(') {
      if (stack.length == 0) {
        caculStrs.add(new StringBuffer());
        index++;
      }
      stack.add('(');
      if (stack.length == 1) {
        continue;
      }
    }
    if (caculStr[i] == ')') {
      stack.removeLast();
      if (stack.length == 0) continue;
    }
    if (stack.length != 0) {
      caculStrs[index].write(caculStr[i]);
    }
  }

  if (caculStrs.length != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < caculStrs.length; i++) {
      RegExp inlayMethod = new RegExp(r'[A-Za-z]+\(' +
          caculStrs[i]
              .toString()
              .replaceAll('+', '\\+')
              .replaceAll('*', '\\*')
              .replaceAll('(', '\\(')
              .replaceAll(')', '\\)') +
          r'\)');
      if (inlayMethod.hasMatch(caculStr)) {
        temp['caculStrTemp$i'] = await _invocationMethod(
            inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr)!.group(0).toString());
        caculStr = caculStr.replaceFirst(inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr)?.group(0), 'caculStrTemp$i');
        continue;
      }
      caculStr = caculStr.replaceFirst(
          '(' + caculStrs[i].toString() + ')', 'caculStrTemp$i');
      temp['caculStrTemp$i'] =
          await handleCalcuStr(caculStrs[i].toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error message.

Comment: `String.replaceFirst` requires a non-nullable `Pattern`, but the result of `inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr)?.group(0)` is `String?`, which might be `null`.  You say you tried using `!`, but I don't see that in your code, so it's not clear *where* you used it. Furthermore, using `!` is inappropriate if the match might fail.

Answer (score 1):

As @jamesdlin already commented **Pattern** is the base class for **RegExp** and for **String**. **Strings are substitutable for Patterns.**
see https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.0/dart-core/Pattern-class.html

It looks like the issue is that `inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr)?.group(0)` is nullable and return string?, so calling `.group(0)` if its a null on it will throw an error.

You need to add a null check before trying to access `.group(0)`:

```dart
if (inlayMethod.hasMatch(caculStr)) {
  temp['caculStrTemp$i'] = await _invocationMethod(
      inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr)?.group(0).toString());

  if (inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr) != null) {
    caculStr = caculStr.replaceFirst(
        inlayMethod.firstMatch(caculStr)!.group(0), 
        'caculStrTemp$i');
  }
  
  continue;
}
```

This checks if `firstMatch()` returned a non-null match before trying to call `group()` on it.